# Web components: How to work with children?

Tags: web-component, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm currently experimenting with StencilJS to create some web components.

Now I know that there is `<slot />` and named slots and all that stuff. Coming from React, I guess slot is similar to children in React. You can do a lot of stuff using children in React. Things I often did:

1. Check if any children are provided
2. Iterate over children to do something to each child (e.g. wrap it in a div with a class etc.)

How would you do that using slot/web components/stencilJS?

I can get the Host Element of my web component in Stencil using

```
@Element() hostElement: HTMLElement;
```

I use my component like

```
<my-custom-component>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</my-custom-component>
```

I want to render something like

```
render() {
  return slottedChildren ?
    <span>No Elements</span> :
    <ul class="my-custom-component">
      slottedChildren.map(child => <li class="my-custom-element>{child}</li>)
    </ul>;
}
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using slots you don't need to put a condition in your render function. You can put the no children element (in your example the span) inside the slot element and if no children are provided to the slot it will fall back to it. 
For example:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <slot><span>no elements</span></slot>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answering the comment you wrote - you can do such a thing but with some coding and not out of the box. Every slot element has an `assignedNodes` function. Using that knowledge and the understanding of Stencil component life cycle you can do something such as:

```
import {Component, Element, State} from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'slotted-element',
    styleUrl: 'slotted-element.css',
    shadow: true
})
export class SlottedElement {
    @Element() host: HTMLDivElement;
    @State() children: Array<any> = [];

    componentWillLoad() {
        let slotted = this.host.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot') as HTMLSlotElement;
        this.children = slotted.assignedNodes().filter((node) => { return node.nodeName !== '#text'; });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <slot />
                <ul>
                    {this.children.map(child => { return <li innerHTML={child.outerHTML}></li>; })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is not an optimal solution and it will require that the style of the slot should have display set to none (cause you don't want to show it).
Also, it will only work with simple elements that only need rendering and not requiring events or anything else (cause it only uses them as html string and not as objects).

Comment: Okay that's true ofcourse. Still that doesn't solve the problem of wrapping each child of the host component into - for example - a <li>-element.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for the answer Gil.

I was thinking of something similar before (setting state etc. - because of timing issues that might come up). I didn't like the solution though, because you're then doing a state change within componentDidLoad, which will trigger another load just after the component did load. This seems dirty and unperfomant.

The little bit with `innerHTML={child.outerHTML}` helped me alot though.

It seems like you can also simply do:

```
import {Component, Element, State} from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'slotted-element',
    styleUrl: 'slotted-element.css',
    shadow: true
})
export class SlottedElement {
    @Element() host: HTMLDivElement;

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {Array.from(this.host.children)
                          .map(child => <li innerHTML={child.outerHTML} />)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I thought you might run into timing issues, because during `render()` the child elements of the host have already been removed to make space for whatever `render()` returns. But since shadow-dom and light-dom coexist nicely within the host component, I guess there shouldn't be any issues.

I don't really know why you have to use `innerHTML` though. Coming from React I'm used to doing:

```
{Array.from(this.host.children)
      .map(child => <li>{child}</li>)}
```

And I thought that is basic JSX syntax and that since Stencil is also using JSX I could do that, too. Doesn't work though. `innerHTML` does the trick for me. Thanks again.

EDIT: The timing issues I mentioned will appear if you're not using shadow-dom though. Some strange things start to happen an you'll end up with a lot of duplicate children.
Though you can do (might have side effects):

```
import {Component, Element, State} from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'slotted-element',
    styleUrl: 'slotted-element.css',
    shadow: true
})
export class SlottedElement {
    children: Element[];

    @Element() host: HTMLDivElement;

    componentWillLoad() {
      this.children = Array.from(this.host.children);
      this.host.innerHTML = '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.children.map(child => <li innerHTML={child.outerHTML} />)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. Indeed it should be componentWillLoad and not componentDidLoad wanted to cause only one re-render. Regarding your solution, it's not using the slot element but it still looking better then my dirty solution. One last thing, while Stencil and React use JSX there are differences between how they render the components. This is why currently you can't just use the nodes as node like we do in React.

Comment: I was looking for a way to replace the host children.
Thanks for the `this.host.innerHTML = '';` hint.