# How to get the content of a web component slot in a cypress test?

Tags: cypress, web-component

With a simple template

```
<span><slot></slot></span>
```

and a test

```
mount(<my-component>some text</my-component>);
cy.get('span').contains('some text');
```

This fails because the text doesn't actually exist within the span, it's shown as "#text reveal" in the inspector.
[image]

How can I confirm that the template and web component are actually setup correctly and the text is being rendered in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the shadow root using [`.shadow()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/shadow#Syntax):

```js
cy.get('qa-text[variant=body1]').shadow().find('span').contains('some text')
```

That's how you would access **unslotted** content.

As slotted content is **not moved to the shadow DOM** (it's just *reflected* there for display purposes), this won't work for your example using slots.

This is what should work for the text in light DOM:

```js
cy.get('qa-text[variant=body1]').contains('some text')
```

You can also work with [`assignedNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedNodes):

```js
cy.get('qa-text[variant=body1]').shadow().find('slot').assignedNodes()[0].textContent.to.equal('some text')
```

Also consider [How To Query Through <slot> Using Cypress While Testing Web Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174625/how-to-query-through-slot-using-cypress-while-testing-web-components).

Answer (score 0):

If the slot like Add template

you can use

```html
cy.get('div[slot="heading"]').should('be.visible');
```